# Script working in JSFiddle but not in my local files?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to take a jsfiddle script example found here on stackoverflow to use it on my website...but it's not working well.

I use Dreamweaver CS6. I pasted the code that I have in Dreamweaver in JSFiddle, and it's working correctly. But I try from Dreamweaver with my local files, it's not.

It's the SAME code.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqYvY/)

Any ideas why it's working in JSFiddle but not using local files in the same browser?
I thought it was because of the "onload" jQuery of JSFiddle, but I'm using external jQuery source (Google). I don't get it!

Thanks!

---

EDIT : Here's my page...hosted with PasteHTML. [HERE](http://pastehtml.com/view/c9bdk1m97.html) Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you tried debugging your site with the console?

Comment: I tried, but it does not seems to have any errors. Weird!

Comment: Doesn't _seem_ to have errors? Either it has errors or it doesn't. Are you loading jQuery properly on your site?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at my fiddle. I'm using Google's jQuery link. And everything's fine. I'm not using JSFiddle Jquery. So why, using the SAME code, it's not working elsewhere than jsfiddle? When I try it, it's like jQuery is not loaded...nothing moves

Comment: No idea, I'd need to see your real page with the problem.

Comment: I copied the whole HTML code in the Fiddle I linked in my post. You can see all the code in there. No external script or css. Everything's in there.

Comment: Right but if the jsFiddle works but your page doesn't, that's not going to help is it? It's hard to debug something that works.

Comment: @user1388136 you need to upload the files to a remote server so we can look at them.

Comment: By the way, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Here : http://pastehtml.com/view/c9bdk1m97.html

Comment: You'll see going on my Fiddle and then the link I pasted here. The banners are not rotating. The banners are supposed to be red and fading into each other automaticly.

Comment: I get an error when I go to your pastehtml.com link.  Did you check for errors?

Comment: I use Firebug, and in the "error" tab, there's no error. What error do you get?

Comment: Using Firebug on your pastehtml page, I am also getting an error, but I am at a loss as to why it's creating the error through pastebin and not jsfiddle.  (I have also created a [copy of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CqYvY/1/) that puts the jquery and css in the correct panels, and sets the correct framework. You shouldn't put entire HTML into jsfiddle, just the content of the `<body>` without the `<body>` tags)

Comment: Are you using any type of encoding when you save the files through Dreamweaver? If you're creating the files for pastehtml through Dreamweaver, but coping/pasting the code into jsfiddle, that could be a reason for it

Comment: Yes, I think it's an encoding issue... if I look at the source of your pastehtml page, and change the encoding (via menus View -> Character Encoding) to something other than `Unicode (UFT-8)` you will see `â€‹` appear on line 30 after `}, 2000);`... try forcing the save of the file into UCT-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's an encoding issue.

If you look at the source of your pastehtml page, and change the encoding (via menus View -> Character Encoding) to something other than Unicode (UFT-8), you will see `â€‹` appear on line 30 after `}, 2000);`

If you can force Dreamweaver to save the file in UCT-8 format, then I believe this issue will go away.

It also would explain why the pastehtml site is not working (if the file is copied to the server), and the jsfiddle is working (if you are doing a copy/paste of the code).

Comment: So I should use UCT-8 instead of UTF-8? That should fix it?

Comment: Ack, sorry @user - my mistake, that typo should read "UTF-8" and not "UCT-8". But yes, I believe saving the file in the correct encoding should remove the problem... let me know

Comment: I checked, and the file is already in UTF-8. There's a line in the top that says "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />". Any other idea?

Comment: Try copy the code and pasting into something like notepad... then copy back out of notepad back into Dreamweaver. (I would also recommend using something other than Dreamweaver! There are plenty of good editors out there, and you should really write you mark-up directly, rather than using designers... you'll get much better results)

Comment: @user, can you actually see what I mean with the bad character that is showing in your page?

Comment: Yes I can see the weird the â€‹. So you are saying that I should copy the code from js fiddle for instance, and copy it into Notepad, and then copy it back to Dreamweaver?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15854/discussion-between-freefaller-and-user1388136)

Comment: Oh! Nevermind I did what you said (copy the code into Notepad and copy back to Dreamweaver) and it's working now...? What makes it work now?